# Does marking the same target with Hunter's Mark end the effect of the Cavalier fighter's Unwavering Mark on that target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, fighter, mark

I'm the DM. During one of our games the party's Cavalier used Unwavering Mark on an enemy. Then the Ranger used [*hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) (PHB, p. 251) on the same enemy.

The [Cavalier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Cavalier)'s Unwavering Mark feature (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 30) says:

> This effect ends early if you are incapacitated or you die, or if someone else marks the creature.

I ruled it as *hunter's mark* being a "mark" and therefore ending the effect of Unwavering Mark. However, we still are not sure if that is how it is supposed to work.

**Is the "mark" the skill refers to another Unwavering Mark from another Cavalier, or does it refer to anything that "marks" a creature?**

Answer (score 3):

## They can both mark the same target simultaneously

Since these are two separate features, there's nothing to say that they can't both be active if two PCs use their marks on the same target. In fact, since one is a class feature and one is a spell, it would even be possible for the same PC to have both things simultaneously active against the same enemy if they had access to both (i.e. via multiclassing).

Although they serve a similar purpose and narratively seem similar, they are not the same thing, and a "mark" is not an established game term with any special meaning attached to it.